# uibutton in subview within uitableviewcell not updating according to condition after scroll back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, subview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


        }


    tv.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tv.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    NSDictionary *Data5 = [pro1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *name = [Data5 objectForKey:@"handle"];


      UIButton *c3 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:775];


    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:c3
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:0
                                  multiplier:0
                                  constant:70];


    NSLayoutConstraint *height2 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:c3
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:0
                                  multiplier:0
                                  constant:0];

    [c3 removeConstraint:height];
    [c3 removeConstraint:height2];
    [c3 addConstraint:height];


 if ([name isEqualToString:@"abcd"]) {


            UITableViewCell *updateCell2 = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


            if (updateCell2){


                    [c3 removeConstraint:height];
                    [c3 removeConstraint:height2];
                    [c3 addConstraint:height2];
                }


 }else{

         [c3 removeConstraint:height];
         [c3 removeConstraint:height2];
         [c3 addConstraint:height];


 }

    return cell;
}
```

on first load, condition is working perfectly. c3 button height was perfect on first load according to if else condition. but when i scrolled up then all c3 buttons taken "height2" constraint. if else condition messed. can u help me?

structure is:

-tableview
--cell
---contentview
----view
-----button(c3)

Comment: You can't remove the Constraint as in your implementation, because the reference of Constraint which is in UI is different from which you are creating in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
Create the IBOutlet for the constraint which you want to update in code.

Comment: button is inside uitableview. i cant create iboutlet of constraint. i can use button's constraint through button's tag which is 775.

Comment: i have created custom cell class and created iboutlet in that custom class. after that connected constraint of uibutton with that iboutlet. now i can change height of uibutton within cellForRowAtIndexPath with if/else codition without any problem. Thanks man :)