# IBOutlet for constraint and connect that to a UIButton programatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I want a custom `IBOutlet` for a  constraint on a  `UIButton` so that I can modify it in a `UITableViewCell`. I want to change the height of the `UIButton` using an if/else condition.

Comment: Are you using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: not custom subclass. using with custom cell identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either subclass the UITableViewCell and then link your constraints into that, or use an identifier on your constraint and then get the constraint from the view with a loop like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in subview.constraints) {
        if ([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            return constraint;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I m using identifier of constraint. and i want constraint of uibutton, not uiview. created uibutton with their tag within uitableviewcell.

Comment: The above will work if you do the loop on the cell.contentView subviews. A UIButton is a UIView..

Comment: here is the code link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670468/uibutton-in-subview-within-uitableviewcell-not-updating-according-to-condition-a

can u explain little bit?

Comment: for (c3 in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in c3.constraints) {
            if ([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:@""]) {
                return constraint;
            }
        }
    }
getting error on "return constraint"

Comment: i have created custom cell class and created iboutlet in that custom class. after that connected constraint of uibutton with that iboutlet. now i can change height of uibutton within cellForRowAtIndexPath with if/else codition without any problem. Thanks man :)

Comment: Yeah the custom cell is the easiest way to do what you want. But the way that I suggested means that you don't have to subclass the cell each time, you can just give a constraint an identifier and find it and then update its height. But your way works too.